# Sending Image Files from Android to WCF REST Service

Tags: java, android, image, wcf, service

I have referred lot of solutions but no luck.

I am trying to send Image file from Android to Server using WCF REST Service. But I am able to send only 10KB of image files, other then that I am unable to send.

Early I tried sending Base64 String but I am unable to send using this method. Changed several configurations in WCF config file but still having issues to receive large files.

Below is my Android Code where I have executed asynchronously

*Android Client Code to Send Image Files using WCF REST Service to Server*

```
public void myGoal()
{

       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.courserequest);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    StringBuilder s;


    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        final String URL1 = "http://localhost:8889/PhotoService/WcfAndroidImageService.svc/GetStream";
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL1);

        ContentBody bin = null;

        httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(data));  



        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
         s = new StringBuilder();

        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
        System.out.println("Response: " + s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

*Web.Config File in WCF REST Service to add configuration features*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true"
      executionTimeout="14400"   />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>


    <services>
      <service name="WcfAndroidPhotoServis.WcfAndroidImageService" behaviorConfiguration="BehConfig">
        <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
                 behaviorConfiguration="web"
              contract="WcfAndroidPhotoServis.IWcfAndroidImageService"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8889/PhotoService/WcfAndroidImageService.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>


    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebBinding"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard"
                 sendTimeout="10:15:00"
                 openTimeout="10:15:00"
                 receiveTimeout="10:15:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                        transferMode="Streamed"

                 >

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>




    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BehConfig" >
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"  helpEnabled="true"  defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />


          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"  />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

*Image Service Interface Method in WCF*

```
IWcfAndroidImageService.cs

  [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                UriTemplate = "GetStream")]
        void GetStream(Stream imageData);
```

*Image Service Method to Receive Byte Stream Data From Clients like Android (WcfAndroidImageService.svc.cs)*

```
   public void GetStream(Stream imageData)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                imageData.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                FileStream f = new FileStream("D:\\FileUpload\\SubjectFront.JPG", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                f.Close();
                imageData.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error if so then post it here.

Comment: No, I am not getting any error. I am just able to send only 10KB image files.

Comment: Have you checked your database where you are storing images. Is it declare as enough space to store an image

Comment: I am saving Images as Files but not in database. I have doubt on the web configuration settings to allow large files.

Comment: Please put your text from that code block. You let us sroll and scroll. Why?

Comment: Below is the query I have asked.I have referred lot of solutions but no luck. I am trying to send Image file from Android to Server using WCF REST Service. But I am able to send ony 10KB of image files, other then that I am unable to send. Early I tried sending Base64 String but I am unable to send using this method also. Changed several configurations in WCF config file but still having issues to receive large files.

Below is my Android Code where I have executed asynchronously.Please do the needful where I am doing wrong or any missing things.

Answer (score 0):

```
 imageData.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
 f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

You are doing that only once. So you only get 10000 bytes. The rest is lost.

Make a loop where you keep reading until the end of stream.

```
Int nread = imageData.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
f.Write(buffer, 0, nread);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help and thank you for identifying my mistake. Now I tried to upload the image size of 26,291  bytes, it stored in server with size of 988 KB (1,011,776 bytes). I don't know why the size change. When I try to upload Image size of 99,929  bytes, i can't see any Image file in Server Folder. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: This time I did like below code.  
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
               // imageData.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

                    int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = imageData.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                    } while (bytesRead > 0);

Comment: Put your code in a new code block. Never put code in comments. That's unreadable. As to the change of size: Do not use Bitmap class to upload a file or resource.

Comment: Sure, other than Bitmap class any suggestions to upload an image file from client.

Comment: Before we continue please adapt your post here first. Do all the things i asked you to do.

Comment: I am new to posting queries in Stackoverflow format, I read few help page but I am unable able to do so. Could be help me how to put code in code blocks here.

Comment: You already have three four code blocks. So why do you ask me how to make a code block? Just edit your post and adapt. The first code block should not be one.

Answer (score 0):

add these below code to your WEB.config file in wcf service:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```