# Client cannot connect to Wcf Service

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I would like to upload file to wcf service from android. The service already open but every time connect to the service it fail, stuck at .connect().

After few minutes it throw Exception:

> failed to connect to /10.16.2.56 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT
>   (Connection timed out)

I configure my wcf side almost same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420422/sending-image-files-from-android-to-wcf-rest-service), please help!

Here my code of android :

```
try
{
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeoutConnection = 3000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 5000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://10.16.2.37/wcf3/service1.svc/GetStream");

    ByteArrayBody bab =new ByteArrayBody(data,"001.jpg");
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.addPart("uploaded", bab);
    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    postRequest.setEntity(entity);

    System.out.println("2");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    System.out.println("response");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String sResponse;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        s = s.append(sResponse);
        System.out.println("Response: " + s);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getClass().getName() + ":  " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: part of your code please where you stucked

Answer (score 0):

Its worked for me.

```
package databaseconnect.databaseconnect;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://example.com/IService1/InsertData";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://example.com/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "InsertData";
private static String URL = "http://example.com/Service1.svc?wsdl";
Button Save,Clear;
EditText name,mobile,email;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    Clear=(Button)findViewById((R.id.clear));
    Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
            task.execute();
        }
    });
    Clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name.setText("");
            mobile.setText("");
            email.setText("");
        }
    });

}
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {


        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("name", name.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("mobile", mobile.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("email", email.getText().toString());
        //request.addProperty("name", "testuser");
       // request.addProperty("mobile", "123456789");
        //request.addProperty("email", "sample@google.com");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        String res=null;
        try
        {

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,180000);
            androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            name.setText(e.toString());
        }

        return  null;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}